# Tooltip using d3.bisector in small multiples of stacked area charts is throwing reference errors

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a stacked area chart — or rather, small multiples of stacked area charts — to which I'm trying to add a tooltip that displays values multiple values, as in this block: https://bl.ocks.org/fabiomainardi/3976176cb36e718a608f
as well as this one: http://bl.ocks.org/wdickerson/64535aff478e8a9fd9d9facccfef8929

As I understand it, the result I'd like to achieve (which most resembles that second block) requires the d3.bisect method, since 1) multiple paths/lines are involved, and 2) I'd like, eventually, alongside the y value for each area inside the tooltip, to display the x axis value (i.e., the date), like in this block: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/6eb506b129f585ce5c8a. Maybe getting the x axis value on mousover is another question for another day; but maybe you're feeling generous.

To me, they're related questions in the sense that I'm equally unable to call up either x or y values for the tooltip.

**Here's my Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/ztDPXbLu3dZ6ju4poz84?p=preview

I've tried adapting about six or seven different examples that use d3.bisect to display tooltip x/y values for multiple paths/lines, without success. All of the other examples that I've been working from have a much simpler data structure.

In my various adaptations of other people's tooltips, I've tried summoning dates and y values in the following ways, among others:

```
d.x
d.date
d.dates
arr
data.x
dataset.x
dataset.date
data.x
dataset.x
data.y
d.y
dataset.y
dataset[0].values[1].y
dataset[i].values[j].y
dates.x
date.y
dataset.values.x
data.values.y
d3.max(data.values.y)
```

Predictably, I get a lot of reference errors.

I've managed to get one pseudo-tooltip working. **Here's another Plunker**:
https://plnkr.co/edit/XpXQc6ryvpyPeprAPxH4?p=info

But this only displays totals for the full date range, and only one path at a time. My goal is to display, in the tooltip, both the date and all of the respective y axis values, for each of the paths in the stacked area chart, just like in the second block I referenced earlier.

How do I do this, and can someone demonstrate for me in a forked Plunker, how to make the necessary references to my dataset for such a tooltip?